# Way to persist function result as a constant

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I needed to create a function today which will always return the exact same value on the specific database it's executed on.  It may / may not be the same across databases which is why it has to be able to load it from a table the first time it's required.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PAGECODEGET] ()
RETURNS nvarchar(6)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PageCode nvarchar(6) = ( SELECT PCO_IDENTITY FROM PAGECODES WHERE PCO_PAGE = 'SWTE' AND PCO_TAB = 'RECORD' )

    RETURN @PageCode
END
```

The PCO_IDENTITY field is a sql identity field, so once the record is inserted for the first time, it's always going to return the same result thereafter.

My question is, is there any way to persist this value to something equivalent to a C# readonly variable?

From a perfomance point of view I know sql will optimise the plan etc, but from a best practice point of view I'm thinking there may possibly be a better way of doing it.

We use a mix of SQL Servers, but the lowest is 2008 R2 in case there's a version specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no such thing as a global variable like you suggest in SQL Server.

As you've pointed out, the function will potentially return different results on another database, depending on a variety of factors, such as when the row was inserted, what other values exist in the table already etc. - basically, the `PCO_IDENTITY` value for this row cannot be relied upon to be consistent.

A few observations:

- I don't see how getting this value occasionally is really going to be a performance bottleneck. I don't think best practices cover this, as selecting a value from a table is as basic as you can get.
- If this is part of another larger query, you will probably get better performance by using a join to the `PAGECODES` table directly, rather than potentially running this function for every row

However, if you are really worried:

- There are objects in the database which are persistant - tables. When you first insert this value, retrieve the `PCO_IDENTITY` value, and create a new table with just that in, that you may join to in your queries. Seems a bit of a waste for one value, doesn't it? (Note you could also make a view, but how would that be any better performing than the function you started with?)
- You could force these values into a row with a specific `PCO_IDENTITY` value, using `IDENTITY_INSERT`. That way the value is consistent, and you know what it is - you could hard code it in your queries. (NB: Turn `IDENTITY_INSERT` off again afterwards, and other rows inserted into this table will continue to be automatically generated again)

TL;DR: How you are doing it is probably fine. I suspect you are trying to optimise something that isn't a problem. As always - if in doubt, try out a few approaches and measure.

Comment: Thanks for that insight.  PCO_IDENTITY will never change once inserted since it's the identity of the table so no worries there. There are thousands of records in the same table so ensuring it'll always have the same value across databases is impossible.  We were first using joins but normalised to the function because it was being referenced so often that future changes to it's criteria could potentially cause maintenance inconsistencies.  Your insight at least confirms this is as good as it's going to get.

Comment: As usual with questions which boil down to "what's best for me?", the answer is always "it depends". Good luck!